# count uppercase chars in string recursively

Tags: java, string, count, char, uppercase

I have to solve an exercise, counting all the uppercase chars in a String - recursively - Anyhow I thought I might have found a solution - but it won't work…
Probably you might help me? Thanks!

```
public static int CountCapitals(String s) {
    int counter = 0;
    // if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)))counter+=1;
    if (s.length() == 0)
        return counter;
    if (s.length() == 1 && s.charAt(0) < 65 && s.charAt(0) > 90)
        return 0;
    if (s.charAt(0) < 'A' && s.charAt(0) > 'Z') {
        return CountCapitals(s.substring(1));
    } 
    if (s.charAt(0) >= 'A' && s.charAt(0) <= 'Z')
        counter++;
        return CountCapitals(s.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What problem did you run into with your code? Please explain your specific problem at hand in more detail.

Comment: You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the use of `counter`: each level of invocation has its own `counter`, initially set to zero. The `++` operator at the bottom has no effect.

You need to compute the result of this invocation based on the result of the previous invocation. Your base case (i.e. `s.length() == 0`) is fine; the rest of your code needs to change so that it returns whatever `CountCapitals(s.substring(1))` when the first letter is non-capital; when the first letter is capital, your function should return `1 + CountCapitals(s.substring(1))`.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Additionally, if allowed within the exercise, I would strongly advise using the Java built-in [isUpperCase()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isuppercase.htm) method to avoid shooting yourself in the foot with boundary conditions; but if that's the exercise, then so be it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the case when the length of string is 1 and the only character is uppercase (in this case, you should return 1).

Also you need to pass in the counter as a parameter rather than expecting it to "carry over" into other function calls.

Answer (score 0):

This recursion should do just what you want:

```
public static int countCapitals(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) return 0;
    int cap = Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0;
    return countCapitals(s.substring(1)) + cap;
}
```

If this wasn't a home assignment, you could try an iterative approach which is about 5-10 times faster:

```
public static int countCapitals(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < s.length(); idx++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(idx))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use a `counter` variable to keep track of the number of capitals.  Instead, you can just the recursive calls, themselves, to keep track of the total:

```
public static int CountCapitals(String s) 
{
    if (s.length() == 1)
        return (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0);
    else 
        return CountCapitals(s.substring(1)) + 
               (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0);    
}
```

If this is for an assignment and you have to use ASCII values, then fine, but if not, you really should just `Character.isUpperCase(char c)`. In case you're not familiar with the conditional operator, it's defined as follows:

```
if(someExpression == true)
{
  //output 1
}
else
{
  //output 0
}
```

is represented succinctly as:

```
(someExpression == true) ? 1 : 0
```

NB:
In your example, `counter` is set to 0 at the beginning of each method call, so that's why it's not working.  If you *really* want to use a `counter`, pass it as a parameter to the method instead, and update the parameter with each method call.  When you get to the end of the `String`, simply return the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You try this

public class HelloWorld{

```
public static int isUpperCase(String str){

    if(str.length()==0) return 0;

    boolean check =Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0));

    if(check){

      return  isUpperCase(str.substring(1))+1;
    }

    return isUpperCase(str.substring(1));
         
 }



   public static void main(String []args){

    String n= "FSAsdsadASdcCa";
    System.out.println(isUpperCase("FSAsdsadASdcCa"));
  
 }

}
```